# How does one solve a cubic polynomial with complex coefficients?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials

I have found formulas online for the the roots of a cubic polynomial with real coefficients, but they all said this they would not work for polynomials with complex coefficients.  I need to solve the following:
$x^3+cx^2+\alpha$ where $c>0$ and $\alpha\in\mathbb{C}$.  Anyone have the formula

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[In my answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15865/why-not-write-the-solutions-of-a-cubic-this-way/18873#18873), I give a cubic formula that works for complex coefficients and works with the way principal roots are defined on non-real complex numbers in the vast majority of calculators and computer algebra systems.

Answer (score 7):

As Moron says, Cardano works. [You merely need to be a bit more careful than usual.](http://books.google.com/books?id=w47cyQLVQowC&pg=PA228)