# How may I solve this Cubic Equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, cubics

How can I solve this cubic equation?

$$H^{3} − 3\left[(1 + A\cos(T) )^{2} + \frac{2r \cdot A \sin(T)}{B}\right]H + 2(1 + A \cos(T))^{3} = 0$$

Solution in terms of H.

Edited in order to give more insight to my problem:
It was an equation which comes as a part of a derivation in Computational Fluid Dynamics. My motivation is to get H in terms of A, B, r and T. And plot a graph between H and r keeping A and B and T as constants.

Thanks!

A general doubt: If a cubic equation consists of a imaginary root, then is it compulsory that the number of imaginary roots should always be 2?

Comment: I am not sure about the tag and the formatting. Can anyone please help me correct the question? Thanks! 
@Chandru1: Thanks for the editing!

Comment: Cubic equations have an explicit formula for the roots (like the quadratic formula).  Techniques for solving them are discussed here:http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function      There may be easier ways, but you are assured of getting an answer.

Comment: Are the values $A$, $B$, and $r$ positive?  If not, where do they live?

Comment: Where did you get this equation from? What is your motivation?

Comment: [My answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15865/why-not-write-the-solutions-of-a-cubic-this-way/18873#18873) contains an explicit formula for the solutions to a general monic (leading coefficient 1) cubic that works on most contemporary computing devices/software without any extra worrying about definitions of principal roots.

Comment: @DJC: I have Edited the problem to give a better insight.

  @Isaac: Thanks. That was a very nice way of solving cubic equation.. :) Let me see if i can get some intuition from this kind of a solution.

Comment: @bala, the fundamental theorem of algebra states that a cubic equation has 3 roots. Any imaginary root must be accompanied by its complex conjugate, so a cubic either has 3 real roots or 1 real root and two complex roots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Write it as $H^3 + qH + p = 0$;
2. use [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+h%5E3%2Bq%2ah%2Bp%3D0+for+h) or [formulas for roots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation);
3. plug in for *q* and *p*.

Comment: The 2a) is a very Interesting Step! Thank you. Still it would be nice, if i am able to derive it further. because there are 2 imaginary roots and i'll get polynomial of a very high degree for Sin and Cos. Isn't there a better way to simplify the equation?

Comment: A general doubt: If a cubic equation consists of a imaginary root, then is it compulsory that the number of imaginary roots should always be 2?

Comment: @bala maverick: Yes.  In general, for a polynomial with real coefficients, any complex roots come in conjugate pairs, so if $x + iy$ is a root for real $x$ and $y$ then $x - iy$ is a root.  And since a cubic only has three roots (including multiple roots) there is either a conjugate pair of roots with imaginary parts or no roots with imaginary parts.